# SimpleXLSX выдает ошибку: Compressed size is not equal with the value in header information

Tags: php

При попытке чтения файла *.xlsx* (корректно открывается в Excel) с помощью `SimpleXLSX`, выдает ошибку

> Compressed size is not equal with the value in header information

Вот такие строки влияют на ошибку:

```
$aP = unpack('v1VN/v1GPF/v1CM/v1FT/v1FD/V1CRC/V1CS/V1UCS/v1FNL/v1EFL', $vZ); 
......
if (strlen($vZ) != $aP['CS'] ) {
                $aI['E'] = 1;
                $aI['EM'] = 'Compressed size is not equal with the value in header information.';
```

Comment: strlen($vZ) = 1679583

Comment: $aP['CS'] = 3240419

Comment: Какой версией SimpleXLSX пользуетесь?

Comment: SimpleXLSX php class v0.6.5

Comment: Гугл говорит, что есть версия 0.6.8.

Comment: Мне SimpleXLSX пришлось самому допиливать. Там много чего нет. Много сделано очень убого. Если открываете только XLSX файлы, советую переделать распаковку файла с помощью Zip

Comment: была такая идея,наверно так и сделаю